# Get Value From a NumPy Array

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
```

A and B arrays are in good order.

```
A = np.array(['a','b','c','d','e'])
B = np.array([5,7,3,9,11])

C = np.array(['a','b','k','j','p','x'])
```

For each element of array C, if that element is in A, get value from B of the same position as B. If not in A, write np.nan.

The expected result would be:

```
result = np.array([5,7,na,na,na,na])
```

How is the easeist way of doing it in numPy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`np.in1d(C, A)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to determine if `C` is in `A`.

```
In [110]: np.in1d(C, A)
Out[115]: array([ True,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Then use `np.where` to select the desired values from `B` or `np.nan`:

```
In [116]: np.where(np.in1d(C, A), B, np.nan)
Out[116]: array([  5.,   7.,  nan,  nan,  nan])
```

[`np.where(cond, B, np.nan)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) returns an array of the same shape as the boolean array `cond`.
The returned array takes a value from `B` if the corresponding value in `cond` is True, and is `np.nan` otherwise.

---

If `len(C) > len(B)`, and if you would like the final array to contain `NaN`s for the last `len(C)-len(B)` values, then you could use:

```
N = len(B)
result = np.full(len(C), np.nan)
result[:N] = np.where(np.in1d(C[:N], A), B, np.nan)
```

Comment: Thanks, accepted !, Unfortunately ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (18,) (19,) () if A and C are NOT in same shape. How to do in this case?

Comment: That could happen if `B` is shorter than `C`. What do you want to happen if an element in `C` is in `A` but there is no corresponding value in `B`?

Comment: Both A and B are same shapes.

Comment: If an eleemnt in C is present in A, get corresponding value from B. If not in A, get np.nan

Comment: If `C = np.array(['a','b','k','j','p','a'])` then what should the result be?